Is Elastic Builder object has enough for a .build()?
Using the Java Elastic 8 client, how do I know if the
 co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.DisMaxQuery.Builder 

that I instanciated has queries ? There are different cases and the builder may actually not have queries in the logic of my implementation.
If I do .build() and it doesn't have queries, it gives an error.

Whenever we initialize the builder object in Elasticsearch Java, it starts with default values, but some builders come with predefined defaults.
For example, a SearchQuery builder may have default values for parameters like from, size, etc., and similar defaults are present in other filters as well. For every builder, there are required parameters that must be provided, such as index, query, etc. If you try to build the query without providing the required parameters, it will throw an error.
In Elasticsearch Java, there are different types of query builders, and one of the main advantages is the ability to build queries using lambda expressions.
